# what is the right way to assignment (type A) a to (type B) b without much cost?

Tags: c++, eigen

here is the things. when i try to assign a typeA value to type B value,it cost much time.

```
  auto tmp = (a * b.transpose());//a and b both are Eigen::MatrixXf,cost pretty zero
  std::cout << (double)(clock() - t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "------11" << std::endl;
  t = clock();
  auto tmp1 = tmp.array();//cost pretty zero
  auto res = 1 - tmp1;//cost pretty zero
  std::cout << (double)(clock() - t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "------22" << std::endl;
  t = clock();
  Eigen::MatrixXf rse= res;//**much cost**
  std::cout << (double)(clock() - t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "------33" << std::endl;
```

thats the things.

Comment: Be careful. A lot of Eigen processes (delayed execution) return proxies rather than actually do the operations. So you have to make sure that prior operations are completed before you start timing things.

Comment: This question is about assigning a *specific* type to another *specific* type. However, using the wording "typeA" and "typeB" suggests it applies to *any* type, such as `int` and `float`.